# What does it mean to say that a function is integrable with respect to a measure?

Tags: real-analysis, integration, measure-theory

What does it mean to say a measurable function is integrable with respect to a measure, such as $\mu$? I know the definition of integrability, but I'm still not sure what exactly what "with respect to a measure" means.

For example, with Riemann integration, for a function of one variable, $f(x)$ say, we know we are integrating with respect to $x$ and $x$ is clearly in the integrand. How should I interpret $d\mu$? Or $d\mu(f^{-1}(B))$?

This question is to help me understand Radon Nikodym derivatives.

Comment: Well, the definition of integrability on a measurable space involves a measure. In a measurable space you can introduce different measures, and they can change the collection of integrable functions.

Comment: Thank you. I edited my question because it wasn't complete. To expand, what exactly does $d\mu$ mean? Is it the same interpretation as $dx$?

Comment: in a first time, you should interpret $\int_{[a,b]} f d\mu$ as a generalization of $\int_a^b f(x) \mu'(x) dx$ where $\mu'(x) \ge 0$.

Comment: What is $\mu^{'}(x)$? I'm doing a Probability Theory course, so our measure is $\mathbb{P}$. Thanks for your patience.

Comment: the derivative of some function. at first, try with $\mu'(x) = 1$ ... the generalization is instead of considering some non-negative function $\mu'(x)$, defining a "measure" $\mu([a,b]) = \int_a^b \mu'(x) dx$, defining the axioms of the LHS : $\mu(A) \ge 0$ for any subset $A \subset \mathbb{R}$,  $\mu(A \cup B) = \mu(A) + \mu(B)$ when the sets are disjoints, and after you defined what is a measure, forgetting  about the RHS (and hence of the existence of that derivative) and generalizing even more with the Lebesgue integral

Comment: and in probability theory, we also require that $\mu$ (or $\mathbb{P}$) is a probability measure, not only a measure, i.e. : $\mu(]-\infty,+\infty[) = 1$, intuitively this means that $\frac{d}{dx} \mu([a,x])$ (aka. the function $\mu'(x)$ above) is a probability density function, and that $\mu(A) = P(X \in A)$ for some random variable $X$

Comment: Yes. This is where it gets confusing, with Radon Nikodym derivatives. That's why I asked my question, even though it sounds trivial. I'm looking at push forward measures and I want to understand everything.

Comment: try with the Dirac measure $\mu(A) = 1$ iff $0 \in A$, you'll see why the derivative $\frac{d}{dx} \mu([a,x])$ is not well-defined for discrete distributions (hence why we consider some sort of generalization including these cases)

Answer (score 2):

A measurable function is integrable with respect to the measure $\mu$ if

$$\int_\Omega |f(x)| d\mu < \infty$$

If you change the measure, you change which functions are integrable.

For exemple if $\mu$ is the dirac in 0, then every function is integrable (assuming a function at value in $\Bbb R$)

Comment: Thank you. I did edit my question above: is there an intuitive interpretation of $d\mu$? Or $d\mathbb{P}$?

Comment: @LiveFreeorπHard $d\mu$ is a merely symbol. It is there to remind you which measure you're integrating against.

Answer (score 2):

Unlike the $dx$ in Riemann integration, $d\mu$ is simply a notation. It does not mean the infinitesimal change in $\mu$. It is written that way to resemble Riemann integration and avoid the necessity to introduce more symbols.

To define integrability, let's look at simple functions. An example would be
$$ \phi = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k \chi_{S_k}
$$
where $\chi$ represents a characteristic function. Notice that $\bigcup_{k=0}^{n-1} S_k = \Omega$ and $S_k$s are disjoint is another criterion for $\phi$ to be a simple function. The **integral** of $\phi$ is
$$ \int_\Omega \phi\,d\mu = \sum_{k=0}^{n-1} c_k \mu(S_k)
$$
Now, for a measurable function $f:\Omega \to [0,\infty]$, its integral is
$$ \int_\Omega f\,d\mu = \sup\left\{ \int \phi\,d\mu \mid \phi \leq f, \phi \text{ simple} \right\}
$$
That is, the supremum of the integrals of all simple functions less than $f$. Finally, if $f:\Omega \to \mathbb{R}$ is measurable, $f$ is **integrable** if
$$ \int_\Omega |f|\,d\mu < \infty
$$
and if $f$ is integrable, its integral is given by
$$ \int_\Omega f\,d\mu = \int_\Omega \max(0,f)\,d\mu - \int_\Omega \max(0,-f)\,d\mu
$$

Comment: In the Riemann integral the dx does certainly not mean any infinitesimal variation of anything, either!

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Alvarez Maybe in nonstandard analysis?

Comment: Well, since most humans that encounter Riemann integration have no idea what nonstandard analysis is, that's sort of moot

Comment: Thank you! Okay, just to be clear: when we say a measurable function is integrable with respect to a measure, we are talking about the measure that is being used on the simple functions which will ultimately be used to determine $\int_{\Omega} f d\mu$?

Comment: @LiveFreeorπHard Yes. There is a long chain of theorems that determine this, but it is all based on simple functions.

Comment: @HenryW. : he already read that in his course... I don't see the point of writing the course again.

Comment: @ Henry W. Thank you, thank you, thank you! I've used simple functions many times to prove "simple" results, and then used Montone or Dominate Convergence Theorems to prove the results in general, but I really wanted to know what exactly was meant by $d\mu$.

Comment: @LiveFreeorπHard It means you are integrating w.r.t. $\mu$. This will make more sense in Radon-Nikodym derivatives.

Comment: Yes! And I'm a little confused with Radon Nikodym derivatives, that why I was motivated to ask my question.

Comment: @LiveFreeorπHard Overall it is just notations.